# "Database does not exist" when trying to create a new Postgres database with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-artisan

I want to create a Postgres database from PHP. This is my code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $schemaName = 'new_database';
    $port = env('DB_PORT') ?: '5432';

    // Connecting to postgres
    $pdo = $this->getPDOConnection(env('DB_SAMPLE_HOST'), $port, env('DB_SAMPLE_USERNAME'), env('DB_SAMPLE_PASSWORD'));
    
    $pdo->exec(sprintf(
      'CREATE DATABASE %s;',
      $schemaName,
      'utf8',
      'utf8_unicode_ci'
    ));
}


private function getPDOConnection($host, $port, $username, $password)
{
    return new PDO(sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;port=%d;sslmode=prefer', $host, $port), $username, $password);
}
```

All of this happens inside a Laravel/Artisan command. The `handle` function is the entrypoint. I expect this code to connect to a Postgres host in `getPDOConnection`, then create a database with `exec`. Instead, I get this error (I removed the actual *user* and *password* values):

```
1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "new_database" does not exist")
    /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=postgres;dbname=new_database;port=5432;sslmode=disable", <user>, <password>, [])
    var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

What's the problem here? It seems there is something I totally misunderstand, as the error message is telling me that the database I just wanted to create does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure that the credentials you have in hand is having the required privilege to create a new database ? (or actually you want to create a table ?)

Comment: I do want to create a database. All of this happens in a Docker/container context, so it may very well be a permissions issue. I'm investigating this at the moment. But shouldn't I get a different error message in this case?

Comment: The error message states that you execute `PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=postgres;dbname=new_database;port=5432;sslmode=disable", <user>, <password>, [])`, when creating the pdo you pass by the database (`...;dbname=new_database...`), does the database exist at this point?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I realized that the `__construct function` in the error message is similar to the code inside `getPDOConnection` only by coincidence. The error message seems to come from a migration command, while my PHP code seems to have silently failed. After building the relevant image again (which I had tried multiple times before), everything is working now. Unfortunately, I don't know what was the problem, but my code seems to work.